# EventEmitter creation

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between following:

```
new require('events').EventEmitter();
```

AND

```
var events = require('events');
new events.EventEmitter();
```

The first one is not working, but second one - works.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the difference between these lines:

`new foo().bar()`

... and ...

`new foo.bar()`

In the first case `new` operator will change how `foo()` function is processed: it will be used as a constructor (with `this` pointing to its prototype copy etc.)

But in the second case `new` operator cannot be applied to `foo`, as the latter is *not invoked*: it's its `bar` property that is called instead. Naturally, `new` here means `foo.bar` is used as a constructor instead.

And that's exactly what happens in your example: the first case tries to apply `new` to `require` function call, not to `%require_result%.EventEmitter` one.